# What IP/Port is my Expo-App using with React Native?

Tags: spring-boot, api, react-native, expo

I have built an API with Spring-Boot, which send some JSON as response.

After I set the @CrossOrigin-Annotation on my Spring-Boot-App, I‘m able to fetch the data without any problem.

Now I want to fetch from the same API with my React-Native-App (running with Expo App (iOS)).
Unfortunately I only get an Network-Error.

I added Localhost:19002, the IP from the Expo-Server and my Phone-IP to the CrossOrigin-Annotation.

Same Error.

**The API should be fine, so my Question is:**

What IP is Expo using, to fetch my Data from the API?

I hope, someone can help me - as I‘m pretty new to this (Web)App-Topic

Greetings

Daniel

Comment: Is the server ip port 19002?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the Expo client app on your device, `localhost` will refer to your phone and not your computer.

You will need to use your network ip address for your computer to reach it. You can get that programmatically while in development by using `Constants.manifest.hostUri` but that will include the port as well.

```
// be sure to run expo install expo-constants first
import * as Constants from 'expo-constants';

let host;
if (__DEV__) {
  // eg: 192.168.1.1:19000 -> 192.168.1.1
  host = Constants.manifest.hostUri.split(':')[0];
} else {
  host = 'https://your-production-server-url.com/api'
}
```